# How to check if string contains numbers symbols

Tags: asp.net, html, regex

I have asp.net(c#) web form with html input text(first name) how i can check if string contains symbols, numbers, unicode text, space with c# 
or its more easier with html?

I want to user entered only first name

Comment: Pre-submission form checks are best done with a quick Javascript test

Comment: @DaveEveritt - but you should _always_ validate on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression will only match on one or more ASCII characters:

```
^[A-Za-z]+$
```

You can use the above in either Javascript or .NET.